# jquery ui progressbar not calling file on setinterval method online but working fine offline

Tags: php, jquery

in one of my applications; i am using jquery ui progressbar to display the progress of task. In that i have used setinterval method in js to read the progress after a particular time period repeatedly. It was working fine on localhost but when i uploaded it to a server; now the progress_track file is called only once and its not being called again after the interval. Below is the code for that:

```
var myInterval = setInterval(function () {
    /* get progress status */ 
    (jQuery).getJSON('includes/progress_track.php?filename=<?php echo $file;?>', function (data) {
        /* update jQueryUI progressbar */ 
        (jQuery)("#progressbar").progressbar({
            value: data,
            /* onComplete actions */
            complete: function (event, ui) {
                (jQuery)(this).progressbar("destroy");
                (jQuery)(".progressbartext").hide();
                (jQuery)(".progressbar").hide("fast");


            }
        });
        (jQuery)(".progressbartext").html("<span class=\"progress\">" + data + "%</span>");
        /* reset interval */
        clearInterval(myInterval);
    });
    /* 2 seconds*/
}, 2000);
/* prevent from page reload */
return false;
```

Comment: You have two extra `});`. Either you are giving us incomplete code or there is a syntax error.

Comment: sir the problem is not of syntax error.. actually i have given only that part of code which is causing problem. Please help me in this is there some dependencies to make it work online as it is working fine offline..

Comment: I assume your code uses the [Session Upload Progress](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.upload-progress.php) feature of PHP? See the manual for what settings are needed to enable it, and in what environments it can be used or not.

Comment: no sir i am not using session upload progress..so the issue is not of that..actually i am refering code from http://misha.beshkin.lv/jqueryui-progressbar-implementation/ and made some changes for tracking progress but the problem which is caused is that progress track file is not called repeatedly as it is being called offline..